# CKEDITOR 4 auto remove some plugin after build

Tags: ckeditor

When i use command `sh build.sh` to build CKEDITOR 4, all most is perfect but some plugin.js file auto be removed from folder after build task finished.

[image: Build command log]

[image: Log]

[image: build-config.js: 4 plugins in yellow is being removed]

[image: When task finished, have 4 plugin folders but file "plugin.js" was removed]

Image 3: build-config.js: 4 plugins in yellow is being removed "plugin.js" file.

Image 4: When task finished, have 4 plugin folders but file "plugin.js" was removed

Anyone know why some plugin.js was removed?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution is: remove all custom plugin in `build-config.js` file
[image: Remove in config]

Now all plugins be built perfect.